# Finding last 2 digits of $2016^{500}$ without repeated squaring

Tags: number-theory

I wish to reduce $2016^{500}$ mod $100$.

The idea is to use Chinese remainder theorem by first breaking down 100 into $2^{2}$ and $5^{2}$

So then set $2016^{500}$ as x

x is congruent to 0 mod $2^{2}$ obviously

x is congruent to ____ mod $5^{2}$

Then combine the two to get mod 100

But how can I easily tell what "____" is in this case? Wolfram told me it's  1, but how can I tell just by looking at it and how do I apply the same thought process to similar problems

Comment: $2016\equiv 16 \pmod {25}$  A little calculating shows that $16^5\equiv 1\pmod {25}$.

Comment: I understand that but I'm wondering how to see it without the calculation as the exam is done without a calculator

Comment: I didn't use a calculator.  $16^2=256\equiv 6$.  $16^4\equiv 6^2 \equiv 11$   $16^5\equiv 16^4\times 16=176=1$

Comment: So what about $9376^{1000}$ mod $5^{4}$? How do I easily see that's also 1

Comment: $9376\equiv 1 \pmod {5^4}$

Comment: You might be looking for a universal approach to these...if so, I think you are out of luck.  Other than brute force I mean.  With numbers of modest size (and even $5^4$ is fairly modest) you can generally play around with the numbers until you catch a break.  Not exactly a systematic method, I grant.

Comment: On second thought:  your problem is even easier than I said.  $\varphi(5^4)=500$ so if $(a,5)=1$ then $a^{500}\equiv 1 \pmod {5^4}$.

Comment: $9366^{1000}$ is also congruent to 1 mod $5^{4}$

Comment: If you look at my last comment, that follows.

Comment: i see it now, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, $16$ is of period $5$ modulo $25$. You can use (moderately) advanced math to conclude from the fact that $16\equiv1\pmod5$ that $16^5\equiv1\pmod{25}$, or you can just calculate it out: the powers of $16$ modulo $25$ are $16^2=256\equiv6$, $16^3\equiv6\cdot16=96\equiv-4$, $16^4\equiv-4\cdot16=-64\equiv11$, $16^5\equiv11\cdot16=176\equiv1$. All without calculator.

Since $16^5\equiv1\pmod{25}$, you have $16^{5n}\equiv1$ as well. Thus your $2016^{500}$ is congruent to $0\pmod4$ and to $1\pmod{25}$. You can do the rest.